# What is best practice for including an R script within a package?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm writing a component of a data pipeline in R (mainly consisting of reading in some small csv files and reshaping before writing to a database) and am going to run the process in a docker container probably via AWS Lambda. I've written each part of the process as a function which I've put in an R package. The main wrapper function takes a few parameters as inputs, which will be passed to this process in json format. I want to have some way of including a script in my package which takes the json, converts it to an R list, and passes the elements of that list to the function that executes the process, and I guess I will execute this script using `Rscript` in the Dockerfile.

What is best practice for managing a script like this? At the moment my plan is to put the script in the `inst` folder of the package and call it via `source(system.file("myscript.R", package = "mypackage"))`. But I've also read about the `exec` and `demo` subdirectories in `inst` and wonder if this is better? Is there a more formal way of bundling up an R script as an executable as part of a package that is standard practice? I'd really appreciate it if anyone has done something similar and can share a neat solution.

Comment: If you just have a script that is specifically designed for your workflow, you should just copy it to your docker image. R packages are only useful for writing re-usable generic functions. If you have a docker image, you have already a fresh namespace, so there is no need for further packaging.

Comment: @danlooo, packages are very useful to organise and document the code. Depends on the size of the "script", of course

Comment: @DmitryZotikov R packages need to be created whenever a single character of the script changes. This takes time. I think it is not worth if the code will not be reused in the future, because the docker image already isolates your code. Documentation can be applied to everything, it is not unique to R packages.

Comment: "best practice" questions are essentially opinion based questions which are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Can you rephrase in terms of something that can be objectively answered? Otherwise just use whatever works for you. If you want more conversational feedback, try a site like https://community.rstudio.com/ instead.

Comment: @danlooo, OP will have to rebuild the docker image, so it does not really matter - amounts to adding a "devtools::build()" RUN step. Packages are certainly useful besides isolating the code: think testing (you wouldn't want to run untested code, would you?), S3 dispatch, proper documentation, being able to reference objects without the need to `source()` files or making `library` calls, etc - it's just so much nicer and dare I say "right".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it would be best to wrap the code you need execute in a function (`f`) and then call it as

```r
Rscript -e 'package_name::f()' --args "$@"
```